# Can someone Invent formulas of any level?

Tags: feats, pathfinder-2e

Alice took the [Inventor](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=798) feat. Their PC is currently level 10 and have months of downtime. Can they use this downtime to invent the formula to any common item including one that is of a level higher than 10?

Answer (score 7):

The Inventor feat "works just like the Craft activity", and the Craft activity strictly limits crafted items to the level of the crafter or lower:

> To Craft an item, you must meet the following requirements:
> The item is your level or lower. An item that doesn't list a level is level 0. If the item is 9th level or higher, you must be a master in Crafting, and if it's 16th or higher, you must be legendary.

I would therefore rule that a character cannot use the Inventor feat to invent formulae of a higher level than their character level.

Comment: What about the next requirement "You have the formula for the item"? Wouldn't that mean you need the formula for the formula before inventing it?

Comment: @AnneAunyme the Inventor feat explicitly provides a way around that requirement - but not the level cap.

Comment: I initially upvoted, but after reading the Inventor feat, I have to disagree. It doesn't say it "works just like the Craft activity", it says "works just like the Craft activity" then articulates exactly what that means. It doesn't mention a level cap.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz it doesn't explicitly provide a way around the requirement of knowing the formula for the formula (only the formula for the item). By Acacia's reading it would be fair to assume one needs a formula for a specific formula before inventing it (which I agree is silly, but to me that only makes this reading shady)

Comment: @AnneAunyme It's worth noting that formulae are unnecessary for Craft in the remaster, just reducing the amount of setup time from 2 days to 1 day.